# Add a scalar to a numpy matrix based on the indices in a different numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I'm sorry if this question isn't framed well. So I would rather explain with an example.
I have a numpy matrix:

```
a = np.array([[0.5, 0.8, 0.1], [0.6, 0.9, 0.3], [0.7, 0.4, 0.8], [0.8, 0.7, 0.6]])
```

And another numpy array as shown:

```
b = np.array([1, 0, 2, 2])
```

With the given condition that values in `b` will be in the `range(a.shape[1])` and that `b.shape[1] == a.shape[0]`. Now this is the operation I need to perform.

For every index `i` of a, and the corresponding index `i` of b, I need to subtract 1 from the index `j` of `a[i]` where `j== b[i]`

So in my example, `a[0] == [0.5 0.8 0.1]` and `b[0] == 1`. Therefore I need to subtract `1` from `a[0][b[0]]` so that `a[0] = [0.5, -0.2, 0.1]`. This has to be done for all rows of `a`. Any direct solution without me having to iterate through all rows or columns one by one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [numpy indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.indexing.html). See this [post](https://towardsdatascience.com/numpy-indexing-explained-c376abb2440d) for a nice introduction:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0.5, 0.8, 0.1], [0.6, 0.9, 0.3], [0.7, 0.4, 0.8], [0.8, 0.7, 0.6]])
b = np.array([1, 0, 2, 2])

a[np.arange(a.shape[0]), b] -= 1

print(a)
```

**Output**

```
[[ 0.5 -0.2  0.1]
 [-0.4  0.9  0.3]
 [ 0.7  0.4 -0.2]
 [ 0.8  0.7 -0.4]]
```

As an alternative use [substract.at](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
np.subtract.at(a, (np.arange(a.shape[0]), b), 1)
print(a)
```

**Output**

```
[[ 0.5 -0.2  0.1]
 [-0.4  0.9  0.3]
 [ 0.7  0.4 -0.2]
 [ 0.8  0.7 -0.4]]
```

The main idea is that:

```
np.arange(a.shape[0])  # shape[0] is equals to the numbers of rows
```

generates the indices of the rows:

```
[0 1 2 3]
```